# How to separate the edges for each m&m candy?

Tags: matlab

Need to identify, count all the m&m candies and how many of each colour there are but can't seem to work it out. Managed to do the following but they don't seem right. The are "bridges" between the neighbouring ones and some don't get filled.[Default image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k828G.png)

Tried using imfill and strel.[Edited image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQRVk.png)

Comment: Think about a solution that uses the color differences. Please edit the question and add your code.

Comment: https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/01/11/freehand-segmentation-in-the-a-b-plane/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.